# Fast random number generator in C?

Tags: c, random

Why does when I run the random() function in a while loop it does not need a seed, but when I run it outside of a while loop it requires a seed? I am trying to generate random numbers in rapid succession.

Comment: "when I run it outside of a while loop it requires a seed?" is incorrect.  Post your code for more detail.

Comment: If you don't provide a seed you get the same semi-random set of numbers each time (not very random....) Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no random() function in the standard C library.

Comment: @S.M. - POSIX -- returns `long`. (but not in the Standard is correct)

Comment: Fast random number generator:  [return 9;](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int min;int max;
    printf("Enter the random min and random max: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&min,&max);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ran_num = rand() % max + min;
    printf("the random number is %d \n",ran_num);

    return 0;
}
```

You can set the seeds like this:`srand(time(NULL));`,and why you use random function?

Comment: Tip - code-only answers and generally not helpful to others. Please explain the problem your code solves?

Comment: `rand() % max + min` fails to generate [min...max].  Even `rand() % (max-min+1) + min;` fails when  `(max-min) > RAND_MAX` or overflows.

Comment: transforms like that also bias values towards smaller values (i.e. even if you started with uniform generator it's not going to be uniform after this)

Comment: Explain what you can achieved with your code.